# Best way to pass a presenter for a parent views

Tags: java, android, mvp, android-mvp

I am writing multiple layer MVP based application. 
Common methods for all layers goes to a BASE layer. 
Then specific methods for each child classes goes to MIDDLE and TOP layers.

From a code example you can see that i am passing my view for a presenters as a parameter on create method.

My question is how should i pass my presenter to a parent views.
Can i do it as shown in an example where a BASE layer presenter attaches it self to a view when it is created?
Or should a TOP layer fragment (where presenter is created) attach presenter to a parent fragments.

Or maybe there is another way to deal with this kind of situation.

BASE LAYER

```
public interface BaseView extends BaseProgressDialogInterface{
    void setPresenter(BasePresenter presenter);
}

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements BaseView{
    private BasePresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void setPresenter(BasePresenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public void randomEvent(){
        if (presenter != null)
            presenter.doSomething();
    }
}

public class BasePresenter {
    private final BaseView view;

    public BasePresenter(BaseView view) {
        this.view = view;
        view.setPresenter(this);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        //Do something..
    }
}
```

MIDDLE LAYER

```
public interface BaseMainScreenView extends BaseView{
    void startSomeActivity();
}

public class BaseMainScreenFragment extends BaseFragment implements BaseMainScreenView {
    //Can be called from multiple top classes
    public void startSomeActivity (){
        //Starting other activity, do not need a presenter in this class
    }
}

public class BaseMainScreenPresenter extends BasePresenter {
    private final BaseMainScreenView view;

    public BaseMainScreenPresenter(BaseMainScreenView view) {
        super(view);
        this.view = view;
    }

    //Other logic...

}
```

TOP LAYER

```
public interface TopFragmentView extends BaseMainScreenView {
    //...
}

public class TopFragment extends BaseMainScreenFragment implements TopFragmentView {
    private TopFragmentPresenter presenter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        presenter = new TopFragmentPresenter(this);
    }

    public void topEvent(){
        presenter.topAction();
    }
}

public class TopFragmentPresenter extends BaseMainScreenPresenter {
    private final TopFragment view;

    public TopFragmentPresenter(TopFragment view) {
        super(view);
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void topAction(){
        view.startSomeActivity();
    }
}
```